# Should SVN working copy format match the repository version?

Tags: svn, repository, format, version

I have a remote SVN repository that I connect to via HTTPS.  The repository is using Subversion 1.5.1.  I am running OS X 10.7, which I believe comes with SVN 1.6, but I'm not using that at the moment.

When checking out a working copy, which format should I be using?

I was using a working copy format of 1.6.  Is that acceptable if the repository is 1.5, or should I be using a 1.5 working copy format?

Are there any advantages to using a 1.6 or 1.7 working copy format if the repository is 1.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion clients are backward compatible with older server versions excluding some new functions (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/compatibility.html).

The 1.7 client has one huge advantage -- centralized metadata storage. All metadata are stored in a single folder in the root of the working copy.

I would recommend to use 1.7 for the working copy.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  1.7 appears to be working well so far, and the centralized metadata storage is awesome!